# Formatting a button to scale with page and other page elements without using position

Tags: html, css, button, position, alignment

I'm kind of new to CSS and HTML, but I'm attempting to code a website for my time spent in China. Currently, I'm facing the issue of aligning a button with my other contact reference icons and having it scroll properly with the page. I found some CSS format for a button I really liked online, but I'm having some trouble **formatting it to be the same height**, and **centering it on the same horizontal midpoint as my other icons**. I tried adjusting the margins, but to no avail. I've found that when adjusting the position, it just makes the scaling a bit difficult. I was wondering if I could get some help with this. Thanks! I will include a js fiddle with the code.

HTML & CSS:

```css
.Social {
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-left: 29.3%;
}

.Pop {
  margin-left: 0.8%;
  margin-right: 0.8%;
  width: 6%;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3 ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
}

.Pop:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.5, SizingMethod='auto expand')";
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.5, SizingMethod='auto expand');
}

.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 2%;
  padding: 1% 4%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-family: "eraslight";
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button5 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #555555;
}

.button5:hover {
  background-color: #555555;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="Social">
  <img alt="snap circle" class="Pop" src="https://image.ibb.co/cHB5SU/SnapPop.png">

  <img alt="Insta circle" class="Pop" src="https://image.ibb.co/eOtkSU/InstaPop.png">

  <img alt="Wechat circle" class="Pop" src="https://image.ibb.co/dppEMp/WePop.png">

  <img alt="Linkedin circle" class="Pop" src="https://image.ibb.co/effAu9/Linkedin_Pop.png">

  <img alt="Gmail circle" class="Pop" src="https://image.ibb.co/movbZ9/GmailPop.png">

  <button class="button button5"><h2>Résumé</h2></button>
</div>
```

Comment: May I suggest that you trim your code down? Remove the vendor-prefixed CSS rules (add them back later if you feel you must, but - assuming you're not crippling yourself with an older browser - they're not necessary for debugging). When you add them back put the non-vendor prefixed property *after* the vendor-prefixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a height on the containing div and allow children to inherit it. Add `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;` to the container like this:

```css
    .Social {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      height: 40px;
      margin-top: 1%;
      margin-left: 29.3%;
    }

    .Social img, .Social button {
      display: inline-block;
      width: auto;
      height: inherit;
    }


    .Pop {
      margin-left: 0.8%;
      margin-right: 0.8%;
      width: 6%;
      transition: all .3s ease;
      -moz-transition: all .3 ease;
      -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
      -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
      -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    }

    .Pop:hover {
      -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      -o-transform: scale(1.1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
      transform: scale(1.1);
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.5, SizingMethod='auto expand')";
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1.5, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1.5, SizingMethod='auto expand');
    }

    .button {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      /* Green */
      border: none;
      color: white;
      margin-left: 2%;
      padding: 0 4%;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 80%;
      font-family: "eraslight";
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
      /* Safari */
      transition-duration: 0.4s;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .button5 {
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
      border: 2px solid #555555;
    }

    .button5:hover {
      background-color: #555555;
      color: white;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="Social">
      <img alt="snap circle" class="Pop" src="https://image.ibb.co/cHB5SU/SnapPop.png">
    
      <img alt="Insta circle" class="Pop" src="https://image.ibb.co/eOtkSU/InstaPop.png">
    
      <img alt="Wechat circle" class="Pop" src="https://image.ibb.co/dppEMp/WePop.png">
    
      <img alt="Linkedin circle" class="Pop" src="https://image.ibb.co/effAu9/Linkedin_Pop.png">
    
      <img alt="Gmail circle" class="Pop" src="https://image.ibb.co/movbZ9/GmailPop.png">
    
      <button class="button button5">Résumé</button>
    </div>
```

Your HTML remains the same except I removed the `<h2>` tags from your `<button>` text; it is unnecessary and affects vertical alignment in some browsers.

Comment: Wow that's going to be really useful in the future. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

All your elements are being displayed inline; to adjust how inline elements are lined up vertically you should set the `vertical-align` property.

```
img {
    ...
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.button {
    ...
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

To adjust your `.button` to be a better visual fit for its neighbours, you may find removing the `h2` tags, setting your padding to a fixed size and setting your font to a fixed size to be a help.

```
.button {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 5px;
    ...
}
```

```
<button class="button button5">Résumé</button>
```